# Apple look around on rural areas

Tags: maps

I have a question regarding Apple look around mode on Apple maps.

Is there a estimated timeline for when Apple Look Around will also cover rural areas in the US?

thanks

Comment: This site works better if questions contain the question only, and any answers are posted as answers. Off-topic questions are not getting answered at all, there is even less reason to include potential answers in the question. If you want to discuss site policies, please bring it up on Meta.AD.